# Installing Neteans problem with version of JDK

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

[image]

I don't understand what I'am doing wrong, i downalad the newest Netbeans and JDK and something went wrong. Can someone explain me what should I do?

Comment: use and old NetBeans or update your JDK, noting else to do

Comment: [1] I just used the NB installer to install NB 12.5 with JDK 17 and it worked fine. Perhaps there is an issue with the NB installer that has been fixed very recently. Try downloading the installer again [from here](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html), and then install NB 12.5 using that newer download. [2] An alternative approach that also worked for me is to download the zip of NB 12.5 from that same page, unzip it, and then edit file **etc/netbeans.conf** to specify the path to JDK 17, using **netbeans_jdkhome** (i.e. **netbeans_jdkhome="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17"**).

Comment: It's also worth checking your installation of JDK 17. Open a **cmd** window, **cd** to the `bin` directory of your JDK 17 installation and submit  `java --version`. If I do that I get `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724...`. Is that what you see?

Comment: Which jdk distrubution you use? Afaik JDK 17 support for NetBeans 12.5 is experimental. At least for running you might try java 16 or java 11.